# Call function template of class template in external function template

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

I have following constellation:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
  template<typename U>
  A<U> f()const;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
A<U> F(const A<T> &I)
{
   return I.f<U>();//this does not work
}
```

The compiler error on the marked line is:
`error: expected initializer before ‘>’ token`

So how do I write the line correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132

Comment: You have a really, really interesting *constellation*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's two-phase lookup for you. Do this:

```
I.template f<U>();
```

This is necessary because, when the compiler compiles the function template `F()`, it does not know what `T` it might be instantiated with. `A` could be specialized *after* the definition of `F()`, which would only be known the moment `F()` is actually instantiated. Therefore, when the compiler encounters its definition, `I.f<U` could also be, say, a comparison between a member `f` of `A<T>` with some `U`.

In order to resolve this ambiguity, you need to tell the compiler that the opening `<` is actually starting a template instantiation.

Comment: Shame on me I read this in several threads before posting here but did not connect it to my problem. Tanks for the solution and explanation.

Comment: Or, in fewer words, you need to *tell* the compiler whether the name "`f`" is a value (say nothing), a typename (say `typename`) or a template (say `template`), since this information is not available at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
   return I.template f<U>();
```